# error 550 Domain not allowed in header from

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, namecheap

I am trying to get namecheap c-panel email hooked up with my nodemailer server instance but I am unable to find how to do that.

here is my nodemailer code

```js
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: "premium174.web-hosting.com",
   port: 465,
   secure: true,
   auth: {
      user: username,
      pass: password
   },
   connectionTimeout: 30000
});
```

from part in the sendMail method contains the email I am logging in to

I am able to establish a connection the server using these details but I can't send any email, AT ALL. anytime I try to send it the error I get is

```js
code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '550-"Your IP: my-ip-here : Your domain domain-here is not allowed in header\n' +
    '550 From"',
  responseCode: 550,
  command: 'RCPT TO'
```

the send mail part is all correct and it works with the other emails I have but this one just would not work

Answer (score 8):

You can visit Email Routing from cPanel and choose "Local Mail Exchanger" under Configure Email Routing.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks mate, worked for me after trying to find issue in the last 3 days

Answer (score 6):

Ok so what I had to do was to change namecheap email routing to local and it worked :D

Comment: Can you specify more on this? I cant find where to make it local

Comment: @XPD: From cPanel home, find "Email Routing". Select the domain to configure, choose "Local Mail Exchanger", then "Change" to confirm.